# WiFi adapter problems. Should I use a router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, ethernet

I am currently experiencing frequent random disconnections in my home. The network has the following structure:

- A **Router** (provided by my ISP) is connected to **PC 1** (home server) via *ethernet*
- **PC 1** gives internet to many other devices via a WiFi hotspot using a *WiFi Adapter*

**PC 1** (and other PCs connected to **Router** also via *eth*) have an stable connection.

The WiFi hotspot is unstable (temporary disconnections of few seconds) even for devices which are close to the *WiFi adapter*. Currently I am using a TP-Link TL-WN422G. Previously I used a TL-WN8200ND (v2). The former is slightly more stable but it forced me to use a repeater to be able to connect to a distant device (not needed using the latter).

I think that it is not a configuration issue but a hardware issue. The uninterrupted connection lasts from few minutes to hours.

**Q: Should I replace the WiFi adapter with a Router? (why?)** If so, **What features should it have to be able to perform a similar configuration?** I need to be able to connect to the Internet, to **PC 1** and using Chromecast or similar devices.

In case of needing a router. Should I add another network board to **PC 1**?

Answer (score 2):

> PC 1 gives internet to many other devices via a WiFi hotspot using a
> WiFi Adapter
>
> The WiFi hotspot is unstable (temporary disconnections of few seconds)

I view this kind of wireless supply as temporary as it is not as reliable as a decent wireless router.

I suggest picking out a reliable Wireless router and attach it to the main router. In my view a separate wireless router is best (not a board in a computer). Set up the router so it is always ON like your main router. Any modern wireless router will have all features (and more) than any temporary hotspot.

I suggest using ONE subnet and so hook it up as follows:

> LAN Port on the new router to your Network (LAN port).
>
> Give the router a static IP on the main network (outside of the DHCP
> range on the network)
>
> Turn DHCP OFF on the new router.

This will make it work like your hotspot.

Comment: +1 Thank you. What you mean for a "decent wireless" router? I bet that a Linksys WRT3200ACM fits, but in my country it cost one and a half months' average salary. Is a cheap router better than the mentioned Wireless cards?  I prefer that all the traffic pass trough the server (so I can filter/redirect/etc). In such case, which mode should the router support? Must I buy another eth card?

Comment: The LinkSys WRT should be fine.  The router can be attached to the main router as I noted, and then the main router will pass ALL traffic to the ISP modem.

Comment: I mean, the cost of a WRT is unaffordable for a home network in my country because cost 1.5 times the average monthly salary. A much cheaper router, lets say TL-WR940N is still a real upgrade?  Also, I really want to pass all the traffic through PC 1. This way I CURRENTLY can for example:  filtering inappropriate content for children and advertising

Comment: Maybe look for the router on Amazon or eBay (make sure vendor is solid). Decent routers allow rules for filtering content.